# UITableViewCell - Custom cell margins

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have built a UITableView which contains custom cells which are fed from a dynamic array.

My array code is here -

```
 feedData *feedData1 = [[feedData alloc] initWithFeedTitle:@"Fishing Article" FeedGroup:@"articleP" FeedImage:@"blah" FeedDate:@"1/11/13" FeedDesc:@"Check out this swimming article..."  FeedDestination:@"articlesSub" ];
 feedData *feedData2 = [[feedData alloc] initWithFeedTitle:@"Runnung Article" FeedGroup:@"articleP" FeedImage:@"blah" FeedDate:@"4/11/13" FeedDesc:@"Check out this marvellous article..."  FeedDestination:@"articlesSub" ];
 feedData *feedData3 = [[feedData alloc] initWithFeedTitle:@"Runnung Article" FeedGroup:@"articleP" FeedImage:@"" FeedDate:@"4/11/13" FeedDesc:@"Check out this marvellous article..."  FeedDestination:@"articlesSub" ];


 self.HpFeedArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:feedData1, feedData2, feedData3,  nil];
```

I want a margin above each cell - the only way I could figure how to do this was to split the cells up into sections, apply a section header and show one row in each section - my current code is like this -

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return self.HpFeedArray.count;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10.; // you can have your own choice, of course
}


- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *headerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    return headerView;
}
```

I then applied the relevant data to the relevant cells as follows -

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
    cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


static NSString *CellIdentifier =@"CellFeed";
feedData *f = [self.HpFeedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
UITableViewCell *cell;

cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

CellHp_RecArticleWithImage *CellArticle = (CellHp_RecArticleWithImage *)cell;

    CellArticle.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    CellArticle.artTitle.text = f.FeedTitle;
    CellArticle.artImg.text = f.FeedDesc;
    CellArticle.artDate.text = f.FeedDate;
    CellArticle.textLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];




  return CellArticle;
```

The above displays the cells spaced apart - but displays the same data 3 times over!  Can anyone help me get my head around what im doing wrong!?

Cheers
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line

```
feedData *f = [self.HpFeedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

since you splitted your tableView with a row for each section if you use row for the index you will get always 0 since there is only one row. so the solution is

```
feedData *f = [self.HpFeedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
```